# code only works on jsfiddle?

Tags: javascript

I am learning JavaScript from a book and in a code example that I have written from the book it will only work for me on jsfiddle. I have tried Chrome and IE but the prompt does not appear. Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
            var userNumbers = new Array();
            var userInput = 0;
            var arrayIndex = 0;
            var message = '';
            var total = 0;

            while (userInput != 99) {
            userInput = prompt("Enter a number, or 99 to exit", "99");
            userNumbers[arrayIndex] = userInput;
            arrayIndex++; 
            }
            message += 'You entered the following:\n';
            for (var i = 0; i< arrayIndex-1;i++) {
                message += userNumbers[i] + '\n';
                total += Number(userNumbers[i]);
            }
            message += 'Total:' total + '\n';
            alert(message);
        </script>
```

Comment: So what do want us to do?  If it works on jsFiddle, and until you show us different, that's concrete proof it works elsewhere.  Provide a link to your jsFiddle **and** a link to your demo page.

Comment: Have you tried opening the developer tools in Chrome to see what errors you're getting?

Comment: You are missing a `+` on this line `message += 'Total:' total + '\n';`  should be: `message += 'Total:' + total + '\n';`

Comment: So you couldn't just copy & paste the _working_ code from your jsFiddle into your broken page?  Was this a trick question?

Comment: I tried that I copied and pasted the code from my IDE into jsFiddle hit run and it worked but when I copied that code back into the IDE it still did not function

Comment: So jsFiddle can magically run broken JavaScript?

Comment: Please post the link to the "working" jsFiddle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rhNVC/2/

Comment: Sloppy.  If you post it jsFiddle _exactly_ the same as you posted it above, it does **NOT** work.  See:  http://jsfiddle.net/rhNVC/4/

Comment: hit the tidy up button and it works fine. What would the tidy up button do to fix the code all it does is clean up indentation correct?

Comment: Works fine?  Hardly.  Notice how it creates a new line and now `message` **only** contains the word `Total:` and nothing else... it then just ignores the line containing the word `total + \n`.  The result of `alert` is affected greatly.

Comment: You are correct I did not notice it was not displaying the Total of all values input. All is good now though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your line:

```
message += 'Total:' total + '\n';
```

should be

```
message += 'Total:' + total + '\n';
```